# Position[{1, 2, 3, 0}, Except[0]] doesn't return {{1}, {2}, {3}}: why?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following code:

```
Position[{1, 2, 3, 0}, Except[0]]
```

It returns me:

```
{{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {}}
```

Instead of what I would expect:

```
{{1}, {2}, {3}}
```

Why? In the documentation of Except it is written "Except[c] is a pattern object which represents any expression except one that matches c." Shouldn't it work as the way I expect?

Comment: Look at the options for the function. 0 is the head. I'll leave it to you.

Comment: @ciao I am not sure to understand what you mean. There is no option "0" in the function Except when I look at the documentation. Perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: Test: `expr = {1, 2, 3, 0};
pos = Position[expr, Except[0]];
Extract[expr, pos]` -- see if any of the extracted positions matches the pattern `0`. Perhaps you want `Position[{1, 2, 3, 0}, Except[0], 1, Heads -> False]`, if you want "members" of the list.

Comment: @JasonB to some extent but not entirely. Thanks for the link. I actually opened another thread as I think my confusion is related to a more general concept https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288566/understanding-the-output-of-position1-2-3-0-except0-1. Thanks for the other comments they were helpful to fix the issue (but I still don't understand the "why").