# Understanding the output of Position[{1, 2, 3, 0}, Except[0], {1}]

Tags: list-manipulation

I am disturbed with the use of the levels in mathematica (my question is motivated by a technical issue [I asked here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288564/position1-2-3-0-except0-doesnt-return-1-2-3-why?noredirect=1#comment718441_288564)).

Consider the following expression:

```
Position[{1, 2, 3, 0}, Except[0], {1}]
```

My understanding of this code means "find all elements not equal to "0", precisely at the level 1 of the list {1, 2, 3, 0}.

It returns me:

```
{{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}}
```

I understand that the {0} means the list itself, but I don't understand the why it is printed given my level {1} specification. Indeed, if I look at the tree associated to the list {1,2,3,0}, the level {1} is only composed of the elements 1,2,3,0 and not the list itself.

[image]

One way to remove the issue is to write instead:

```
Position[{1, 2, 3, 0}, Except[0], {1}, Heads->False]
```

But why should I add Heads->False. Shouldn't the fact I specified {1} for the level be enough to ignore the heads?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the fact that your elements are in a list because `Position` works also for any other expression (try `Position[f[1, 2, 3, 0], Except[0], {1}]`). The positions are wrapped in a list because they can be multi-leveled, for example try `Position[{{a, a, b}, {b, a, a}, {a, b, a}}, b]`. To assure the output is consistent regardless of the multi-leveldness, all positions are returned as a list. I suggest looking through the documentation for [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html).

Comment: Have you seen this?: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Expressions.html#31184

Comment: The level of a subtree corresponds to the length of its position: `Extract[{1, 2}, {{0}}]` (level 1, part 0) vs. `Extract[{1, 2}, {{}}]` (level 0). It's also the length of the `Part` specification: `{1, 2}[[0]]` vs. `{1, 2}[[]]`. The head of an expression is a distinguished part with an important semantic role determining which set of definition-rules may be applied in rewriting the expression (ignoring upvalues). Its distinctiveness is probably why the `Heads ->...` option was included in expression-structure functions.

Comment: "I understand that the {0} means the list itself" -- not the list (not `List[1, 2, 3, 0]`), but the symbol `List`. -- To interpret levels from `TreeForm` takes care: The level consists of the subtrees, not each symbol/expression in a yellow rectangle. The rectangles contain either a head (which is part 0 of level 1 of the subtree, or part 0 of the corresponding element of the next level down) or an atomic expression. The tooltip of the rectangle shows the actual element of the level. They use the head as a label because usually it's shorter.

Comment: As @MichaelE2 mentioned, the head is part 0 of level 1 (it was very helpful for me to see it explained that way, thanks!). You can check it yourself with `Level[{1, 2, 3, 0}, {1}, Heads -> True]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I find your explanation very insightful. Would you consider converting it into an answer?

Comment: @MarcoB Too late. I was putting an answer together when the question was closed. Oh well.

Answer (score -2):

In fact, even you specified {1}, it still doesn't ignore the heads

```
In[1]:= Level[{1,2,3,0},{1},Heads->False]
Out[1]= {1,2,3,0}

In[2]:= Level[{1,2,3,0},{1},Heads->True]
Out[2]= {List,1,2,3,0}
```